# How to search case insensitive with find shortcut in linux terminal(ctrl+shift+f)

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I am using find shortcut in linux terminal (**ctrl+shift+f**) quite often. The problem is that it is case sensetive, so searching for example: "syn/ack" is no the same as "SYN/ACK".

I've researched over the ethernet, but didn't find how establish case insensetive especially for this particular case.

All my researches were pointing nearly to same topic as this:

Which tells to put `set completion-ignore-case On` into **/etc/inputrc**

It worked only for TAB autocompletion like `$> des+[TAB]` -> `$> Desktop/`

So the **2 main questions** here:

1. Is there a way to make find shortcut case insensetive ?
2. Will this configuration be different for different linux shells ? Im using **Kali linux** distribution with **zsh** shell in **qterminal** at the moment, will it vary for bash shell or  MATE terminal for example ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QTerminal, to change to not to match case, press the downward pointing arrow button and uncheck the “Match Case” checkbox.

Source: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.3/qterminal.html

Comment: omgush it was really that simple, didn't notice that button over there, kinda tricky one :D